# R DBI Sparklyr DBWritetable running with no result

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, sparklyr, r-dbi

Coming from an MS-SQL environment into a HIVE environment that also has spark access. Right trying to use RStudio and R (and sometimes python using rPython) to replace some things I used to use T-SQL for as well as a whole host of things I never could do before.

In order for this to work I will need to be able to read and write back to the HIVE DB.

I have connected using spark and the R package sparklyr and can connect to our HIVE cluster using the R package DBI with the spark connection and pull data into R dataframes just fine:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", spark_home="/usr/hdp/current/spark-client", config = config)
result3 <- dbGetQuery(sc, "select * from sampledb.sampletable limit 100")
```

The above code works everytime. I can also create tables within the DB in the context of a quoted sql statement using dbGetQuery without problems so its not a write permissions issue.

However, when I try to write data from an R frame back to the HIVE cluster like so:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = sc, name = "sampledb.rsparktest3", value = result3)
```

It runs without error but the table does not show up and I cannot query it.

If I try to write the table again I get this error:

```
> dbWriteTable(conn = sc, name = "sampledb.rsparktest3", value = result3)
Error in .local(conn, name, value, ...) : 
Table sampledb.rsparktest3 already exists
```

Any ideas what could be happening? Is there a better way I should be doing this besides DBI?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Below is the entire RStudio console log from when I run these statements:

```
> result3 <- dbGetQuery(sc, "select * from sampledb.sampletable limit 100")
> dbWriteTable(conn = sc, name = "sampledb.rsparktest3", value = result3)
> result3y <- dbGetQuery(sc, "select * from sampledb.rsparktest3 limit 2")
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: sampledb.rsparktest3; line 1 pos 35
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:120)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:120)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:44)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:102)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:97)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:62)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:52)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> dbWriteTable(conn = sc, name = "sampledb.rsparktest3", value = result3)
Error in .local(conn, name, value, ...) : 
Table sampledb.rsparktest3 already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

with a sparklyr connection use the  spark_write_table instead of dbWriteTable to write back to Hive

Comment: Thanks edgar, however when I try to use spark_write_table it won't accept R data frames and doesnt recognize my spark dataframes.          
   > 
    spark_write_table(spark_iris, spark_iris2)
    Error in UseMethod("spark_write_table") : 
     no applicable method for 'spark_write_table' applied to an object of 
    class "data.frame"

Comment: Hi, the call should be something like this: `spark_write_table(spark_iris, "hive_iris")`.  The first argument `x` should be a Spark DF, and the second the name of the table inside Hive

Answer (score 0):

Writing Spark table to hive using Sparklyr:

Loading local dataframe to spark:

```
iris_spark_table <- copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite = TRUE)
sdf_copy_to(sc, iris_spark_table)
```

Creating a table in hive (append database name if necessary):

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "create table iris_hive as SELECT * FROM iris_spark_table")
```